# How can I find hpcviewer in order to visualize trace data generated by hpcrun?

Tags: hpc

My question is about `hpcviewer` which is a tool to visualize trace data generated
by hpcrun.

I succeeded to install `hpctoolkit` but I have a problem finding `hpcviewer`.
To test the toolkit, I created a simple hello_world program in C (with `OpenMP`) and executed the following block of commands as shown in https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/HPCToolkit_by_example:

```
gcc -O3 -fopenmp  hello_world.c -o hello_world -lm
hpcstruct ./hello_world
hpcrun -t ./hello_world
hpcprof -S hello_world.hpcstruct -I . hpctoolkit-hello_world-measurements
hpcviewer hpctoolkit-hello_world-database
```

Unfortunately, I get an error which is "`hpcviewer: command not found`".
I installed hpcviewer yesterday using

```
spack install hpcviewer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hpcviewer command is not found because the hpctoolkit has not been loaded.

You should execute the following command before asking for hpcviewer to visualize trace data generated by hpcrun:

```
spack load hpctoolkit
```

Then you can execute

```
hpcviewer hpctoolkit-"name_of_exec"-database
```